# Android native toolchain gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, cross-compiling, gradle-experimental

I'm familiar with the `android-gradle-experimental` family of plugins including the standalone native plugin. However, I have shared libraries that I build for many platforms. I also want to cross compile them for the android platform in order to use them in android library/app projects. Is there a clever way to simply have the standalone native plugin provide toolchains and platforms to gradle while ignoring all the android-centric build types, flavors, and archiving logic (gradle has since added that functionality)?

Something like:

```
apply plugin 'com.android.model.native'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
    }
    components {
        main(NativeLibrarySpec) { // eg.
            targetPlatform 'osx_x86-64'
            targetPlatform 'android_armeabi'
        }
    }
}
```